# How can I display div.class when hovering li.class?

Tags: css, html, hover

On the page [biztone.co](http://biztone.co), in the left sidebar, I am trying to display social share links in a div(.item .details .post-meta), when the main div(#sidebar .recent-post-thumb li) is hovered. I've kind of got it working, except the div(.item .details .post-meta) appears in the box below the hovered box.

Here's the css script I have added to get it to work. But, I need help figuring out why it's displaying in the box below and not the box being hovered..?

```
.item .details .post-meta { display:none; }
sidebar .recent-post-thumb li:first-child:hover + .item .details .post-meta {
display:block; }
sidebar .recent-post-thumb li:hover + .item .details .post-meta {
display:block; }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and will teach me something new.

Comment: Are you insisting on CSS only or are you ok with a javascript solution?

Comment: I would prefer not to have to load Javascript.

Comment: Show your ([relevant/sscce](http://sscce.org/)) HTML *here*, please, don't make us trawl through the whole codebase of your website to find the problem. Also, having the HTML here helps the question retain its value once your problem's solved and the code's corrected (assuming it *can* be).

Comment: And/or consider putting the relevant code in a JSFiddle so we can fork and experiment...

Comment: JSfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/kg9wU/  Thank you all.

Comment: Wololo was able to solve this for me. Thank you all for your consideration and input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#sidebar .popular-post-thumb li:hover .post-meta` is what you need for a selector instead of going to the next dom element with the `+`

Change `sidebar .recent-post-thumb li:hover + .item .details .post-meta` to
`#sidebar .popular-post-thumb li:hover .post-meta`

Comment: Yes! Thank you tons, Wololo! I was unaware that + sends to next dom.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `+` sign: it targets the *next* element.

Remove it and it will target the `.post-meta` element inside the currently hovered li.